# CSS float+align properties produce unexpected results

Tags: html, css

Why does my Favorite starter type dropdown look like this? I want it to be similar to how the email and favorite pokemon generation looks. What does this float right align left thing do exactly?
[image]

```css
.form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.form input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}

.form label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 id="title">Pokemon survey</h1>
  <p id="description">Everyone likes Pokemon right?</p>
</center>

<div class="form" id="survey-form">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input type "text" id="name-label" name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email: </label>
  <input type="email" id="email-label" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br><br><br>
  <label for "favorite-generation">Favorite Pokemon generation: </label>
  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="8"><br><br>
  <label for="favorite-type" id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">Favorite starter type:<label>
      <select id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">
        <option value="fire">Fire</option>
        <option value="water">Water</option>
        <option value="grass">Grass</option>
      </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: Just noting tat you have some typos: `type "text"` instead of `type="text"`; `for "favorite-generation"` instead of `for="favorite-generation"`

Comment: If you use chrome I highly suggest learning how to use the inspector. I was able to identify this problem within a minute

Comment: isn't type="text" fine as well? Idk that's what I'm learning currently, I have = between for all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you accidentally put it inside a `<label>` tag

the reason why is this line

> `<label for="favorite-type" id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">Favorite starter type:<label>`

You didn't close the label tag (you wrote `<label>` instead of `</label>`)

if you want the `<select>` to be on the right too you'll have to add this css rule:

```css
.form select {
  float: right;
}
```

Here is the code with the proper closing tag (I also added the `float: right` to the select):

```css
  .form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.form input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}

.form select {
  float: right;
}

.form label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 id="title">Pokemon survey</h1>
  <p id="description">Everyone likes Pokemon right?</p>
</center>

<div class="form" id="survey-form">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input type "text" id="name-label" name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email: </label>
  <input type="email" id="email-label" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br><br><br>
  <label for "favorite-generation">Favorite Pokemon generation: </label>
  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="8"><br><br>
  <label for="favorite-type" id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">Favorite starter type:</label>
  <select id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">
    <option value="fire">Fire</option>
    <option value="water">Water</option>
    <option value="grass">Grass</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

.form input {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  float: right;
}

/* .form label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
} */
select{
  float: right;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 id="title">Pokemon survey</h1>
  <p id="description">Everyone likes Pokemon right?</p>
</center>

<div class="form" id="survey-form">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input type "text" id="name-label" name="Name" placeholder="Enter your name"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email: </label>
  <input type="email" id="email-label" name="email" placeholder="Enter your Email"><br><br><br>
  <label for "favorite-generation">Favorite Pokemon generation: </label>
  <input type="number" id="number" min="1" max="8"><br><br>
  <label for="favorite-type" id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">Favorite starter type:</label>
      <select id="dropdown" name="favorite-type">
        <option value="fire">Fire</option>
        <option value="water">Water</option>
        <option value="grass">Grass</option>
      </select>
      </div>
```

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for